# How to remove Whitespace from PowerAutomate Compose action output?

Tags: html, power-automate, strip, removing-whitespace

I have a Power Automate workflow which takes fields from Sharepoint lists and puts them into a pdf using the Compose action to create HTML and then convert to a pdf. There are a bunch of conditions within the Compose action such as:

`if sharepoint_field = 'Yes' then 'Show this' else ''`
Since I have a bunch of these blank strings, it is adding a lot of random whitespace between text in the final output. Is there a way I can remove the whitespace and blanks that are added due to all the conditions after the Compose action in Power Automate before it is converted to a pdf?

These if then else statements are in separate

tags and wrapping each of them in a trim still creates line breaks so I'm guessing the cleaning up of whitespace will have to happen after the compose action

[image: multiple paragraph tags with if then else statements]

This is what the expressions look like:

```
<p><b> trim(if(equals(outputs('Get_item')?['body/SharepointField/Value'], 'Yes'), 'Details:','')) 
</b> <span...> trim(if(equals(outputs('Get_item')?['body/SharepointField/Value'], 'Yes'), outputs('Get_item')?['body/SharepointField'],''))</span></p>
```

So inside the `<b>` tags is the Question, and I want it to print the Question only if SharepointField Value is 'Yes' then inside the `span` tags is the answer if Sharepoint Field value is 'Yes', if it gets to the `else` tag then it is just a blank. so multiple of these blanks add up and create a bunch of blank space in my final pdf.

This is the output pdf:[image: output pdf showing all the space between the p tags which I want to get rid of]

Comment: One function you are looking for is `trim`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have wrapped all my if then else's in Power Automate with a ```trim``` but still no luck.

Comment: Hard to help more without specifics.

Comment: Screenshots help … A LOT

Comment: @Skin Just added some screenshots and more explanation.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added some more specifics/explanation to the post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update to the question.
You are going to have to add all your html in the if statement....

```
if(equals(outputs('Get_item')?['body/SharepointField/Value'], 'Yes'),
concat('<p><b>Details:</b> <span...>', outputs('Get_item')?['body/SharepointField'], '</span></p>'),
''
)
```

---

Leaving the below just in case it helps others...

I suspect it isn't the blank strings in the if statements, but the white space between your tags in the Compose action. Sharing a screen shot of your Compose would be helpful.

For example, the blue "-" is a line break, the blue "|" is a space
[image]
So maybe look to remove all white space between your tags, and add the required whitespace within your if statements. Like:
[image]
And your if statement could then be like:

```
if sharepoint_field = 'Yes' then 'Show this ' else ''
```

or if needing a line break:

```
if sharepoint_field = 'Yes' then concat('Show this', decodeUriComponent('%0A')) else ''
```

Comment: I checked and made sure that I don't have any whitespace between my tags and still can't get rid of the whitespace on my output pdf. I have updated the screenshots to show the PDF output and the entire compose

Comment: See the first part of my answer (updated) - you will need to include all of your html in your if statement. Essentially, as you have it now, regardless of the if statements, the html is outputted (ie multiple <p>...</p> even though they are empy.